# Can't Create Reliable "Watch Folder" in UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

```
public class WatchFolder
{
    public bool ChangesMade { get; set; }

    public WatchFolder()
    {
        ChangesMade = false;
    }

    public async void InitializeFolderWatch()
    {
        var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("TestWatchFolder");
        var options = new QueryOptions();
        options.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
        var fileQuery = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
        fileQuery.ContentsChanged += OnContentsChangedFolder;
        var files = await fileQuery.GetFilesAsync();           
    }

    private void OnContentsChangedFolder(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
    {
        ChangesMade = true;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get a watch folder working for a Windows 10 Store app.  When debugging the above code works fine at first.  The event fires and will continue to fire every time I add a file to the watch folder (or remove one) using Windows File Explorer. But if I interact with the [uwp](/questions/tagged/uwp) app's UI for a few seconds then then try again it won't fire thereafter.

I have tried instantiating it in both the code-behind and the view model, same result.  I've also tried converting it to a static method, same result.

Comment: I think it is because the `fileQuery` object is going out of scope and when u r interacting with the UWP app, the GC is kicking in and removing the object from memory.

Comment: try to make the `fileQuery` object a private field in the class, this way it wont go out of scope until you don't need the class anymore.

Comment: This solved it.  Post this as an answer if you like and I will mark it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `fileQuery` object is going out of scope and when you are interacting with the UWP app, the GC is kicking in and removing the object from memory.

try to make the fileQuery object a private field in the class, this way it wont go out of scope until you don't need the class anymore.